# Evaluate an and inside an and SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How would I get SQL to evaluate this as 2 and statements rather than 4?  The left and the Len should be evaluated together.

```
where LEFT([KeyCode],8) <> 'BOS09864'and len([keycode])>8 
and LEFT([KEYCODE],8) <> 'BOS04450'and len([keycode])>8
and [keycode] not in ('STDFJ927','STDFJ928','STDFJ960','STDFJ928NX')
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your code is non-standard SQL) Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: You have four filtering conditions, two of which are identical. Why do you want them repeated? There's more to your question you are not explaining.

Comment: I don't but I need the len to be evaluated with the left, the left condition isn't valid unless the len condition is also true.

Comment: Couldn't you just do something like `len([keycode]) > 8 and [keycode] not like 'BOS09864%' and [keycode] not like 'BOS04450%'`?

Comment: So I want to select where the first 8 characters of keycode <> BOS09864 and length of keycode is > 8. But also where first 8 characters of keycode <> BOS04450 and length of keycode is > 8 and keycode isn't in the list.     where LEFT([KeyCode],8) <> 'BOS09864' and len([keycode])>8 and LEFT([KEYCODE],8) <> 'BOS04450'and len([keycode])>8 and [keycode] not in ('STDFJ927','STDFJ928','STDFJ960','STDFJ928NX')

Comment: @melpomene that would work but there is another and after all of that which doesn't have to meet the len requirement.      and [keycode] not in ('STDFJ927','STDFJ928','STDFJ960','STDFJ928NX')

Comment: You've lost me. I'm back to not understanding the question.

Comment: So `KeyCode` has to be >8 length? Can `KeyCode` be exactly 8 characters, except they instances you mentioned above?

Comment: I have added more info to the original post. Hopefully it is more clear.  The problem is as I have it written is it won't select anything at all that isn't > 8 characters.  I only want it to require 8 characters for the left condition to be met.

Comment: @Shawn no, keycode can be any length, but I only want to exclude the left condition where keycode is > 8 characters.

Comment: Use SQLFiddle.com to create an example of data you're working with and include an expectation of which records you want to return.

Comment: `[keycode] not in ('STDFJ927','STDFJ928','STDFJ960','STDFJ928NX') and [keycode] not like 'BOS09864_%' and [keycode] not like 'BOS04450_%'`

Comment: Does your query involve more than one table?

Comment: @melpomene that works perfectly, thank you.  I didn't know about that _% to get it to not pickup an exact match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using a NOT IN

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE LEN([KeyCode])>8
  AND LEFT([KeyCode],8) NOT IN ('BOS09864', 'BOS04450')
  AND [KeyCode] NOT IN ('STDFJ927','STDFJ928','STDFJ960','STDFJ928NX')
```

But if you also want to retrieve those that are lower or equal than 8, then try NOT with the LEN and IN conditions within parenthesis.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE NOT (LEN([KeyCode])>8 AND LEFT([KeyCode],8) IN ('BOS09864', 'BOS04450'))
  AND [KeyCode] NOT IN ('STDFJ927','STDFJ928','STDFJ960','STDFJ928NX')
```

Using 2 NOT LIKE's with an underscore would get the same result as the previous query.
This might be faster if there's an index on KeyCode.
But it's a poor golf-code when you want to reject more of those Keycodes.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE [KeyCode] NOT LIKE 'BOS09864_%'
  AND [KeyCode] NOT LIKE 'BOS04450_%'
  AND [KeyCode] NOT IN ('STDFJ927','STDFJ928','STDFJ960','STDFJ928NX')
```

Comment: I would add: `and [Keycode] is not null` to avoid poor performance of `NOT IN` constructions

Comment: That could depend on if Keycode is nullable, and if it's nullable then how much are NULL.  But I don't think that adding it would actually help performance.

Comment: Yeps, if `keycode` is non nullable it is not required. It is just a default reflex when `NOT IN` is involved :)

Comment: Using the `NOT LIKE` should definitely still allow the query to use an index, whereas I don't think `LEFT()` would. And if `KeyCode` is `NULL`able, you could either use a `COALESCE()/ISNULL()` or a `UNION ALL`, depending on how many `NULL`s there are.  And for future readers, the `_` is a placeholder character with `LIKE`, so `BOS09864' wouldn't get excluded since it's not more than 8 characters, but `BOS09864X` would. When used right, `NOT LIKE` can be pretty cool . :-)

Comment: Well, the request is a bit confusing. If you look at the comments then it seems that the OP actually wants to reject keycodes as 'BOS09864XX' but not 'BOS09864'

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple values from the same column that you want to exclude from your results, you can use NOT IN to list them out:

```
LEFT([KEYCODE],8) NOT IN ('BOS09864','BOS04450')
```